# How to delay evaluation of JSX passed as props children to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

React `16.13`. I'm writing a `Loader` component to handle different failure states and passing the "successful" content as a child like this:

```
<Loader
    isLoading={loading}
    isError={error}>

    <div>{this.props.loadedContentFromRedux}</div>
</Loader>
```

The Loader component is quite simple:

```
class Loader extends Component {

render() {
    return this.props.isLoading ? <Spinner /> :
    this.props.isError ? <Error /> :
    this.props.children
}

}
```

As I understand, because I am passing the `loadedContentFromRedux` props to the child directly, it is being evaluated before passed as a child to `Loader` and therefore evaluating it prior to the `Loader`'s render method called.

Is there a way I can delay evaluation to prevent this or do I need to guard against it? Or perhaps clone the child and pass the props that way?

Comment: Could you pass in a function that just returns the value? Then you could call the function in the Loader component and it would evaluate the value at that point.

Comment: @jpthesolver2 ah so something like `<Loader data={() => mydata}>`?

Comment: Why does `<loader>` needs `loadedContentFromRedux` ? it should only show a loader and nothing else.

Comment: @vsync `loadedContentFromRedux` is props coming from the parent component of Loader, not Loader itself if that makes sense?

Comment: @crockpotveggies Yeah exactly, then it should just be like a lazy load for the prop

Comment: what is the actual problem? is there a bug? it there an error?

Comment: @vsync yes this compiles but triggers an error at runtime, the props from the parent `this.props.loadedContentFromRedux` is evaluated as null prior to actual desired evaluation, so if i call a child of that object then it fails with `cannot call property of null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const loadedContent = () => <div>{this.props.loadedContentFromRedux}</div>

<Loader
 isLoading={loading}
 isError={error}
 loadedContent={loadedContent}       
/>
```

Change the Loader component to:

```
class Loader extends Component {

render() {
    return this.props.isLoading ? <Spinner /> :
    this.props.isError ? <Error /> :
    this.props.loadedContent()
   }
}
```

By doing this you r not executing the loadedContent while passing, so that `this.props.loadedContentFromRedux` execution will not happen.
It will execute in `Loader` component in render method.

## Edited Answer

I was able to build upon this and change the syntax a bit so it is easier on the eyes and pass the function as a child. It requires a type check in the `Loader` render as such:

```
<Loader
 isLoading={loading}
 isError={error}>

{() => <div>{this.props.loadedContentFromRedux}</div>}

</Loader>
```

Then guard against a function type as follows - this is because the JSX is sometimes prematurely evaluated:

```
class Loader extends Component {

render() {
    return this.props.isLoading ? <Spinner /> :
    this.props.isError ? <Error /> :
    typeof this.props.children==='function' ? this.props.children() :
    this.props.children
   }
}
```